# Find combinations of integers or double such that their sum is equal to a certain number

Tags: algorithm

How to find all the combinations integers, double or negative numbers, such that their sum is equal to a certain number.

For example, suppose I have the following set of numbers:

```
{1.5, -6.7, 10.6, 9.0, 100, -34.5}
```

And I want to find all combinations of those numbers such that it's equal to -39.7, then {1.5 , -6.7, -34.5} would be a combination, since 1.5 + (-6.7) + (-34.5) = -39.7.

All the solutions I found so far only deal with integers.

Comment: it's classical LIS problem : at each step either take that element or leave it, use a bitmask to mark taken values;

Comment: This is a subset sum problem. If the range is not very high try pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming solution. If number of values aren't high then you can enumerate all the subset and find a solution in O(2^n) time. If this is too high then try branch and bound algorithm for 0-1 knapsack.